# sendmail putting mails to non-existing hosts into local accounts

Tags: sendmail

I have a problem with Sendmail, and couldn't find any information about it despite spending hours on Google.

On a linux server ("myserver.com"), I have local users, e.g. users "john" and "mary".

User "john" - through his mail client and authenticating correctly on his account "john@myserver.com" - sends an email to "mary@bogus-non-existing-host.com".

Sendmail instead of rejecting the email, puts the same in the mailbox of local user "mary".

Some configuration in Sendmail to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: It's hard to quantify the joy of converting from sendmail to postfix. There's just so many benefits to doing so, if only for the much larger base of users that can help with issues when they arise.

Answer (score 0):

Got already an answer at the sendmail usenet group: problem was caused by a wildcard CNAME DNS record.
Sendmail appends the hostname of the server to the bogus (unresolved) hostname, and does another DNS lookup, which will be positive if there's a wildcard CNAME record.
Removing the wildcard CNAME record solved our problems.